# Has anyone successfully added more than 8GB Ram to Dell 0K0DNP MB?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Has anyone successfully added more than 8GB Ram to Dell 0K0DNP MB? That is the maximum on the Dell site, but I know people have over-Ramed various computers. Although there are questions regarding "over-ramimg", none are specific. This is asking a specific question about a specific MB.

Comment: I was able to successfully go to 16 G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take the confusion out of the issue. What does Crucial or Kingston say
>   about the memory capacity of the computer?
>
> The manufacturers manual is a snapshot in time, it only reflects what
>   the manufacturer tested, when the manual was being written. They are
>   rarely updated, unless a new version of the computer / motherboard /
>   etc comes out.
>
> Kingston & Crucial are willing to test with newer memory chipsets,
>   etc. So if they say your model will accept more, then it should work.

Kingston and Crucial both state:

Standard Memory: 0 MB (Removable)

Maximum Memory: 8 GB

Comment: Thank you. That is what I finally found, although I couldn't find it on Kingston.